# print strfitime in perl

Tags: perl, strftime

Here is my current code:

```
print "<td class=resa>@res[$i]->{'signupdate'}</td></tr>\n";
```

I want to modify the variable `@res[$i]->{'signupdate'}` to be a *formatted date*. The data is `201710130915` for that variable.

I've tried:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
my $date=strftime('%Y-%m-%d',@res[$i]->{'signupdate'});
print "<td class=resa>$date</td></tr>\n";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unrelated, but it's `$res[$i]->{'signupdate'}`. The sigil has to change if you get a scalar value out. Perl should give you a warning about that if you have `use warnings` turned on (which of course you do, right?).

Comment: What happens when you do use the code that you said you've tried? Do you get wrong output? Where did you get `strftime` from? POSIX?

Comment: @simbabque look at update

Comment: And what is the value of `$res[$i]->{'signupdate'}`?

Comment: @simbabque 201710130915. i dont think thats a unix timestamp actually.

Comment: That does not look like a unit timestamp. It looks more like `2017-10-31T09:15`

Comment: yeh so is there a formatting function i can use

Comment: You can do simple string manipulation. But your assumption that it's a unix timestamp is wrong. If it was, it were the 10th of December 8361. Uhm. :P

Comment: If you _had_ a unix timestamp, you would have to pass it into `localtime` to get the list of arguments that `strftime` expects.

Comment: @simbabque i realize its not a unix timestamp now. do you have any code examples you can show for formatting this into a readable format?

Comment: Just let me write an answer. You have enough rep to know that things shouldn't be rushed...

Comment: @simbabque sorry if you thought i was rushing you. please take as much time as you need.

Comment: You're going to go facepalm now. :)

Comment: Oh, I see Perl is not your usual language. You should have said that. Let me know if you need any syntax explained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156702/discussion-between-simbabque-and-jkushner).

Comment: You were just talking about _casting as int_. Perl does not have data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you have looks like a string representation of a date.

```
YYYYMMDDhhmm
201710130915
```

It can therefore easily be deconstructed with a pattern match and put back together in a different format.

```
my $time = "201710130915";

my ($year, $month, $day) = $time =~ m/^(....)(..)(..)/;
my $date = sprintf '%d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $day;

print $date;
```

This will print

```
2017-10-13
```

Comment: all i get is 00-00-00

Comment: I think it has to do with `@res[$i]->{'signupdate'}` which holds the time

Comment: `my $date = join '-', unpack 'A4A2A2', $time`

Comment: @Borodin that would have worked as an answer. Without explanation, also. This was not the learning kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're running this code without `use strict` and `use warnings`. With those in your code (and you should always include those in your code) you would have got a pretty clear warning.

Your code is basically this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $input = '201710130915';

my $date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', $input);
print $date;
```

And running that, gives this:

> Usage: POSIX::strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1)

Your instinct to use `strftime()` was good. But you need to give it the right input. You're giving it a date/time string. When, actually, it wants individual inputs for all the different date/time values. Effectively, it needs the list of values that is returned by `localtime()`.

You could do it by creating an array, adjusting them in the correct fashion, and then passing the bits of that array in the correct order:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $input = '201710130915';

my @date_bits = $input =~ /(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)/;
$date_bits[0] -= 1900;
$date_bits[1]--;
# The zero is for seconds.
my $date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 0, reverse @date_bits);
print $date;
```

But, frankly, by that point you're probably better off just treating it as a text manipulation problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $input = '201710130915';

my $date = join '-', $input =~ /^(....)(..)(..)/;
print $date;
```